# Insert a variable inside a function

Tags: javascript

I'm using swiper to generate 4 different sliders, each one is called using this :

```
var swiper2 = new Swiper
```

What i want is to create a function that will fire the

```
swiper2.slideNext();
```

every 2 seconds, so i used :

```
setInterval(function(){
 swiper2.slideNext();
 }, 2000);
```

This works great.
But as i said, i have 4 different sliders, and i would like to change the number randomly every time the setInterval function is fired

I tried this

```
setInterval(function(){
 var randx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
 swiper + randx.slideNext();
 }, 2000);
```

But it does not work, it returns swiper, not swiperX wher X is between 1 and 4.
And throws an error because swiper does not exist, only swiper1 to swiper4.

This is obviously a lack of knowledge of JS from myself, 
any help appreciated.

Comment: [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) exist for this purpose. Look into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should store all swipers in an array like:

```
var swipers = [swiper1, swiper2, swiper3, swiper4];
```

and then in your interval you call:

```
setInterval(function(){
  var randx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  swipers[randx].slideNext();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: thanks but not working : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slideNext' of undefined

Comment: I just updated the answer, cuz i forgot to remove the +1 in the random function, since arrays start with an index of 0